# How to create an @Immutable Groovy class with default fallback values for fields?

Tags: groovy

We currently utilize the map based constructor in an @Immutable class and pass all field values during instantiation. I'd like to set sensible defaults for fields in case user doesn't supply any value for them during instantiation?

Is there a groovy way (an easy way) to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill in the attributes in the class declaration:

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Person {
    String name = 'john'
}

p = new Person(name: 'percy')
assert p.name == 'percy'

p2 = new Person()
assert p2.name == 'john'
```

**Update:** Groovy fails if any setters is used after creating the object.

```
try {
    p2.name = 'echo'
    assert p2.name == 'echo'
    assert false
} catch(e) {
    assert true
}
```

**Update 2:** Ah, `groovyConsole` to the rescue. `@Immutable` is setting the `name` field in the constructor, thus, the field is, in fact, final.

[image]

Comment: Ah, for some reason I was under the impression that those fields were `final` (my bad). Thanks.

Comment: The fields *are* final. There is nothing in the example to suggest that they aren't. Doc: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Immutable.html

Comment: @MichaelEaster In above example, the field `name` is being assigned a value twice: once at the time of declaration and another time in the implicit map-based constructor. That's not allowed for `final` variables (at least in Java; I'm new to Groovy). Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: @MichaelEaster Indeed. Added a groovyConsole output.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Groovy allows multiple assignments to `final` variables until the constructor completes. Java doesn't allow that so I was confused.